# Python moving pointer to a specific column in a .txt

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I need to print data of variable sizes to a .txt file in a way that it looks like columns, I cannot use \t because then data with large strings will push the following strings and look something like this:

```
NAME                AMOUNT          DATA_2

LARGE STRINGNAME            999.22                 45.550        

NORMALSIZE          1,133.45        1299         

SMALL         248.76         226.800
```

I would like to move the pointer to a desired "column" inside the .txt as if they were coordinates (column,row), relatively to the .txt and not to the strings, how can I achieve this?

Comment: Look at the modules `prettytable` https://pypi.org/project/prettytable/ and `tabulate` https://pypi.org/project/tabulate/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*print data of variable sizes to a .txt file in a way that it looks like columns, I cannot use \t because then data with large strings will push the following strings*

I would use `.ljust` method, simple example

```
data = [("SHORT","100"),("LONGLONGNAME","1000"),("OTHERLONGNAME","100")]
column_width = 15
with open("file.txt", "w") as f:
    for name, value in data:
        f.write(name.ljust(column_width)+value.ljust(column_width)+"\n")
```

`file.txt` content then be

```
SHORT          100            
LONGLONGNAME   1000           
OTHERLONGNAME  100
```

Remember to adjust `column_width` to your needs.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I didn't know about .ljust :)